# asynctask httpost?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to creating apps for android and first time using asynctask. I want to run a httpost in the back ground but keep getting errors. Am I using the correct parameters?. Do i need a postexecute too?

Here is my code

public void send(View v)
    {
        new sendtask().execute();
    }

```
   private class sendtask extends AsyncTask<String,Void, String> {


    String msg = msgTextField.getText().toString();  
    String msg1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String msg2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();


    protected String doInBackground(String...url) {

          try {

               HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:80/test3.php");
               List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);;
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", msg));
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender",msg1));
               nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age",msg2));
               httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));                   
               httpclient.execute(httppost);

               msgTextField.setText(""); // clear text box
             } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
             }
        return null;
```

Comment: Should read what is the message in the Logcat.. WOuld be more usefull than "I got an error"

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the log cat.

Answer (score 1):

OnPostExecute used if you need to update the user interface (you can not update the user interface in method doInBackground (String. .. url)), the parameter received by the OnPostExecute, is the value returned by doInBackground (String. .. url ), not whether your case is relevant to the user inform you if the post was made

Answer (score 0):

You should include the errors also to help in identifying and solving the problem, but in this case the solution is probably the following:

```
private class sendtask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    String msg = msgTextField.getText().toString();
    String msg1 = spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String msg2 = spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString();

    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:80/test3.php");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", msg));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gender", msg1));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", msg2));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            httpclient.execute(httppost);

            return "";
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            return "ClientProtocolException";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "IOException";
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        msgTextField.setText(result); // clear text box
    }
}
```

The important change is that `msgTextField.setText("");` is in `onPostExecute()` now and it receives the text to be shown from `doInBackground()`. You must do every UI change on the main thread, that is, not in `doInBackground()`.